# PHP reverse stored procedures function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

lets say I have the following query in a variable:

```
$sql = "select id, salary, fname, lname from users where id = ? and salary > ?";
```

and an array like this:

```
$params = array (
  0 => '38765',
  1 => '4000');
```

I was wondering if there is a simple of built in PHP to do this to replace the "?" in the query to get the following result:

```
"select id, salary, fname, lname from users where id = '38765' and salary > '4000' ";
```

the query won't be executed by the way, this more of a sting manipulation question than a sql one.

this is as close as I got but it looks like PHP might have something built it for it:

```
foreach ($params as $param){
    $pos = strpos($sql, '?');
    $sql = substr_replace($sql, "'".$param."'", $pos, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think you should use prepare statements available in both mysqli and pdo for executing this query

Comment: Why do you want to "reverse" a prepared statement? Use prepared statements as they're meant to be used! And this question has nothing to do with stored procedures

Comment: PDO's  function execute can execute with a array as param..  ( http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php ).. so it's use is just as simple as `$pdo->execute(array(38765, 4000))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

See this code example from php.net

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-1016

But this variant requires that you work with `PDO`.

See this link for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: sorry, i didn't recognize that the links were in german. I've updated the links to the english version.